# How do I stop my application express after submit process firing on page refresh?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an oracle application express process, written in PL/SQL and it fires off a confirmation email, supposedly when you click on the related button, (It is an after submit attached to the button) however, it is firing every time you refresh the page. Is there a different way of doing this so it only fires when you click the save changes button?

Answer (score 1):

Take note of the execution point attribute. It will won't apply to page refreshes if it's either 'Processing' or 'After Submit'.

You can also associate these after-submit processes with specific buttons, using the 'when button pressed' property.

You may also wish to consider the 'Enable duplicate page submissions' page property.

If you're still having issues, you can build a demo at apex.oracle.com, and updated your question.